# Correctly include aar inside another aar

Tags: android, build, gradle-plugin, aar

I have inherited a system where we have an app which requires a custom aar which is built on top of two more custom aars

So: I have '**connectivity.aar**' dealing with basic connectivity and allows calls to get/send messages and '**parser.aar**' which parses a whole protocol and takes inputs and outputs of bytearrays and structured messages. Those are fine.

I then have a '**Session.aar**' which controls a whole communication session including stuff like keep-alives and other special touches - this obviously needs connectivity and and parsing so it has in its dependencies the implementation of **connectivity.aar** and the **parser.aar**.

Then I have my **app**, which uses a **session.aar** but also sometimes needs to do some extra parsing (**parser.aar**), plus it needs to have some constants from the **connectivity.aar**

In the code I inherited, the app ONLY has a dependency on **session.aar**, without needing **connectivity.aar** and **parser.aar**. However, now that I have updated the code (it was previously building on Gradle 7.2 and is now on 8.0),changing the Java version (from 11 to 17) and generally updating all the other dependencies, I now get errors when building the app, the errors are for missing dependencies which are fixed by adding in the implementation of **connectivity.aar** and **parser.aar** - so now my **app** relies on 3 aars instead of just the one which includes the two others.

Is this a natural consequence of the updates I have made, or is there a way to allow the 'deeper' aars to be seen by my app which I have somehow bulldozed over in my fixes?